# Pythonic method for stacking np.array's of different row length

Tags: python, numpy

Assume I have following multiple numpy `np.array` with different number of rows but same number of columns:

```
a=np.array([[10, 20, 30],
            [40, 50, 60],
            [70, 80, 90]])

b=np.array([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]])
```

I want to combine them to have following:

```
result=np.array([[10, 20, 30],
                 [40, 50, 60],
                 [70, 80, 90],
                 [1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6]])
```

Here's what I do using `for loop` but I don't like it. Is there a pythonic way to do this?

```
c=[a,b]
num_row=sum([x.shape[0] for x in c])
num_col=a.shape[1] # or b.shape[1]
result=np.zeros((num_row,num_col))
k=0
for s in c:
    for i in s:
        reult[k]=i
        k+=1

result=
array([[10, 20, 30],
       [40, 50, 60],
       [70, 80, 90],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.concatenate()`, this is its exact purpose.

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[10, 20, 30],
            [40, 50, 60],
            [70, 80, 90]])

b=np.array([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6]])
result = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```

In my opinion, the most "Pythonic" way is to use a builtin or package rather than writing a bunch of code. Writing everything from scratch is for C developers.